# WebAPI + Azure WebSite + Client WebSite + SSL - how many certs do I need?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, ssl, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

I have a WebAPI solution hosted in an Azure Web Site (`appnameapi.azurewebsites.net`) that has some endpoints exposed to regular http right now.

I also have a client application hosted in a separate Web Site under `appname.azurewebsites.net`.

I purchased `appname.com` from hover and am forwarding `appname.com` to `appname.azurewebsites.net` with masking.  The client application makes requests to `appnameapi.azurewebsites.net` right now, but not encrypted.

My goal is to get SSL working on the web client so that users see SSL in the browser bar, and so that anything that goes from the client to the api endpoints is encrypted.

I went to rapidSSL and purchased a certificate for `appname.com`.  Now I'm not sure if I need to put this in my WebAPI web site, or my client web site.  I've found some documentation on setting up SSL in Azure but nothing that's given me a good grasp of what needs to be done in this scenario.

What's the next step?  Do I need one cert per site, and if not, where does the single cert go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You client web site is `appname.azurewebsites.net`. You have `appname.com` mapped to this. Your SSL certificate is for this domain. So, you will need to put the certificate with the client app. As an end user, if I go to `appname.com`, the certificate your application will present to my browser will be the one you purchased for `appname.com`. This is for the pages rendered by the client web application.

Now, as the browser renders the page from the client web application, say it needs to make jQuery AJAX calls to your web API site `appnameapi.azurewebsites.net`. You can use a domain name for this one as well, some thing like `api.appname.com` but regardless, this will be a cross-origin call, BTW. If this call is also through HTTPS, then for this case also, a valid cert must be presented to the browser. Assuming you have `api.appname.com` which is a sub-domain of `appname.com`, you can use the same certificate you bought from rapidSSL with web API site as well provided it is a wild-card cert, which is obviously more expensive. Otherwise, you will need one more certificate for the web api site (or the domain name if you plan to use one for API) and install that new cert in the api app.

Comment: There is also a intermediate option to create multi domain certificate, which is cheaper than wildcard.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? I see that wild card cert is $199 whereas multi-domain cert is $278 with Rapid.

Comment: I see other way around like this https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-comparison.htm

Comment: I believe the question is related to Rapid SSL.

Comment: Ok, as i see Rapid SSL, they only have two option :( So you are right :)

Comment: You brought up a good point though, pricing difference for different types.